# Default image displayed briefly on resume under iPhone 5

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, iphone-5, default.png

I'm preparing a new build of my app in Xcode 4.5 to fix some issues introduced with iOS 6, but I'm not yet supporting the new screen resolution. A problem I'm seeing on the iPhone 5 is that when resuming the app, the default image is displayed for a few tenths of a second before the resumed state appears. Normally, the resumed state is displayed right away. The transition is not animated, so it is rather jarring and I'd like to fix it. I don't see the problem with any of the following:

1. Devices other than iPhone 5
2. The same codebase built in Xcode 4.3
3. The same build with an included Default-568h@2x.png

So it seems specific to iOS 6 + iPhone 5 + no Default-568h@2x.png. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: i believe i have seen this behavior pre ios 6 pre iphone 5 as well...